# PHP: SQL returning no results when querying ID

Tags: php, mysql

having a bit of a problem here, I am trying to query MySQL results based on the ID in a column of my table and print the results to the front end.

Here is my code block:

```
<?php $carId = $_GET['id']; ?>
<?php 
try {
$carview = $db->prepare('SELECT Make, Model, Colour, FuelType, Year, Mileage, Bodytype, Doors, Variant, EngineSize, Price, Transmission, PictureRefs, ServiceHistory, PreviousOwners, Options, FourWheelDrive, FullRegistration  FROM WHERE FullRegistration = $carId');
} catch (Exception $e) {
  echo "Error.";
  exit;
}
  $cardata = $carview->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)
?>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
    <?php echo "$carId"; ?>

    <?php echo '<ul class="overwrite-btstrp-ul other-specs-ul h4-style">
            <li>Mileage: '.number_format($cardata["Mileage"]).'</li>
            <li>Engine size: '.$cardata["EngineSize"].'cc</li>
          </ul>'
          ?>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If the $GET id matches one of the ID's in my column `'FullRegistration'` I want to print the row to my front end.

The issue I am having is that when I echo `["Mileage"]` and `["EngineSize"]` they are not displaying the values, instead they are nil when printed to the front end.

`FROM WHERE FullRegistration = $carId` should be only showing the row that has the same `FullRegistration` id as the `$GET` id in the URL.

Any idea why I might be receiving null values (BTW I have included the database connection, I just haven't added it to the code block in this example)?

Comment: You should look at mysql security, really your code is very unsafe. As for the issue at hand, what errors do you get? Do you get any information, can you get any data from the DB at all? Try looking for errors, which PHP and Mysql gives you as a developer - http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php

Comment: what does print_r($cardata) say

Comment: @DOCASAREL I have added `<?php print_r($cardata) ?>` and nothing is returned to the front end.

Comment: you are welcome. you are missing the table name between from where

Comment: Ahh I see, I'v added the right table and still it is returning no results :(

Comment: You're using single quotes, which do not expand variables.  Either use double quotes when you want to have php expand your variable `"SELECT ... WHERE FullRegistration = $carId"`, or break out and concatenate `'SELECT ... WHERE FullRegistration = ' . $carId`.  As other have stated, this is not a very safe way to pass data to MySQL.